# How can I change the order of my chrome tabs?

Tags: google-chrome

I am running Chrome on Ubuntu. I have a handful of pinned chrome tabs. When I try to click and drag to change the order of the pinned tabs, chrome instead takes the dragged tab and creates a new Chrome window from it.

How can I change the order of my Chrome tabs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is apparently a bug see:

https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/rwfmpb/just_installed_970469271_on_kubuntu_when_i_try_to/

and

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1279532

It seems to affect the latest Chrome Built

Answer (score 3):

Drag and drop tabs no longer work since the latest update to Version 97.0.4692.71. Maybe it's a bug. That's why I found this post. <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Page up</kbd>/<kbd>Page down</kbd> works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you drag them along the narrow strip that is the tab bar, if you drag a tab too high or low it will produce a new chrome window. I just tried this with two pinned tabs and they move left and right as expected.

If this doesn't work, you may have an extension installed that messes up this functionality. Try disabling the tab related ones and see if it works then, then re-enable them one by one to see which is the culprit.

Comment: I disabled all my extensions. In addition, it is not cause by how I am dragging it....it opens a new window after a couple pixel of drag.

Comment: Can you create a separate new profile and see if it still happens? See here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824

Comment: Browsing as guest profile, the same problem persists.

Comment: Might be a bug then, cfr Taylor's post. Doesn't seem to be reported yet though: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?sort=-stars&q=os%3Alinux%20tab&can=2

Answer (score -1):

It might be because you accidentally dragged it a bit vertically. It must be dragged horizontally to be re-ordered. If you pull a tab more horizontally, it will seperate it into another window. Chrome makes tabs smaller the more tabs there are in a chrome window, causing it to be more likely that you accidentally pulled the tab a bit more vertically. It might also be a bug, of chrome falsely detecting that you were trying to separate the tab from the current window. Try moving the tabs a bit more slowly and a moving them a bit more quote, unquote "perfect". Remove some extensions that you suspect causing the bug, or removing some customization extensions including themes. Hope this helps!