# When I try to move a tab chrome is opening it up in new window

Tags: google-chrome

I like to use chrome tabs and often slide them around to keep them in a logical order.  I've been able to do that on my work computer before.  However, very recently this behavior stopped working.  Now instead of allowing me to move the tab if I drag the tab it always opens it in a new window, and refuses to redock with the original chrome window the way I'm use to it doing.

I'm not sure what changed.  I don't think anything updated.  I'm working on my personal amazon linux 2 vm so It's not as if some automated update would be forced on me without my knowledge.  The only thing I can think of that changed around the time tabs stoped working is that I changed my VNC settings to not compress images to get rid of fuzziness I was getting from VNC, but that shouldn't affect cursor movement so I don't think it would matter.

Any idea how I might be able to get back the ability to move tabs in chrome?

Comment: Are there any extensions installed that could potentially change this behaviour?

Comment: Postman, but it was installed back when tabs were working as expected and doesn't appear to have updated since then, also turning it off doesn't fix the behaviors.

Comment: This sounds awfully familiar, just realised: https://superuser.com/questions/1697625/how-can-i-change-the-order-of-my-chrome-tabs

Comment: @mig that looks like it's likely my issue.  If you want to post that as an answer I'd be happy to upvote and select the answer so you get credit for pointing me to the information.

Comment: Sure... still new to this forum-but-not-a-forum type Q&A formatting :)

Comment: okay, looks like a mod picked it up already :)